# My view(drivers.blade.php) cannot identify a variable from my DriverController index method

Tags: php, laravel-5

My view(drivers.blade.php) cannot identify a variable from DriverController index method? My model name is Driver.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Driver;

class DriverController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $driver = Driver::all();
    return view('drivers', compact('drivers'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //

}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{

    Driver::create($request->all());
    return back();
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
 }
```

This should get all the data from the database and then display them, i'm trying to create a CRUD but i always get this error "Undefined variable: driver (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\drivers.blade.php)".

```
  <h2>All Drivers</h2>

   <table id="example2" class="table table-responsive" role="grid" aria-describedby="example2_info">
<thead>
<tr>
     <th>Fname</th>
     <th>Mname</th>
     <th>Lname</th>
     <th>Phone</th>
     <th>Address</th>
     <th>Hired</th>
     <th>License_no:</th>
</tr>
```

```
     @foreach($driver as $drive) 
     <tbody>
     <tr>
           <td>{{$drive->fname}}</td>
           <td>{{$drive->mname}}</td>
            <td>{{$drive->lname}}</td>

            <td>{{$drive->address}}</td>
            <td>{{$drive->hire_date}}</td>
            <td>{{$drive->license_no}}</td>

     </tr>

 </tbody>

 @endforeach

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your index function your variable name us $driver and you are passing drivers. Change it to following:

```
public function index()
{
    $driver = Driver::all();
    return view('drivers', compact('driver'));
}
```